# Why does Graywytch hate Danielle specifically?

Tags: dreadnought

In *Dreadnought*, by  April Daniels, Danielle Tozer is the titular Dreadnought, who gained the powers of Dreadnought when they were transferred to her by the dying previous Dreadnought.

Danielle is a transgender woman, and this causes her should-be-teammate, Graywytch, to hate her. It *seems* that this is because Graywytch views her as a man. She insists on calling Danny by her previous name (Daniel) and using masculine pronouns. The language that she uses in one of her diatribes supports this, calling Danny “the purest distillation of an evil that has haunted half of the human race since the priests murdered the Goddess,” seeming to imply that this “evil” is a characteristic of men in general. Stereotypical as it may be, it seems she hates men in general, and dislikes Danny because she views her as a man.

However, the previous Dreadnought was a man (as were several other members of the Legion Pacifica). It didn’t seem like Graywytch had any problems working with him, at least anything like the same degree (e.g. threatening to kill him, constantly calling him evil, and saying that he wasn’t a worthy bearer of the mantle).

Why does Graywytch hate Danny so much more than all the other people whom she perceives as men, and whom she works or worked with on a daily basis?

Comment: I have never read the book, but given what you wrote, isn't it likely that Graywytch dislikes Danielle more than the previous previous (male) Dreadnought because she considers a "man" presenting as a woman to be worse than a man. It seems like a strange attitude, but I think there are people who feel that way in the real world.

Comment: @Blackwood - Oh, she's definitely anti-transgender, no question about it. It seems like her motivation is actually viewing men overall as evil, though, which I am trying to reconcile with her with her specific animosity toward Danielle (as opposed to all the cisgender men she interacts with).

Comment: Perhaps we could image a parallel case where (during the cold war) an American scientist views Soviets as evil, but is still willing to work on a joint US-USSR project. The American scientist might still have a particular problem with a US team member who is a defector from the USSR.

Comment: @Blackwood - That could be the beginning of a good answer.

Comment: I appreciate the encouragement, but as I know nothing about the book, I think I should defer to someone who does. A good answer should probably be able to reference the source material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graywytch perceives herself as the victim, the wronged party. That's all there is to it... Beyond the casuistry, mendacity, hypocrisy and diatribe, that's all it is. Let me explain.
She is a feminist, although not an archetypical one. She prescribes to an odd brand of feminism that dictates that superficial categorization of a single chromosome equates to destiny. X or Y, in reality nothing is ever that simple and people are born with all variety of conditions and genetic abnormalities the lead to their appeared sex being different from that stated by their chromosomes.
Despite changing in pretty much every way, Graywytch sees Danny as essentially male, as she grew up as male and possesses a Y chromosome.
As such, no matter what Danny does, GW will always see her as male masquerading as a woman. GW views this as an invasion, the appropriation and diminution of what is essentially female victimhood. As such while she is extremely aggressive, she demonstrates a victim mentality.
In GW's mind, Danny's existence as a woman is an assault on GW. This allows GW to view her aggressive actions as defensive in nature, no matter what happens. No matter what GW does to hurt Danny, it doesn't matter, she was acting defensively, because Danny started it by being a girl.

Also, Graywytch has been massively toned down. The author rewrote her three times because no one would find her believable, despite the fact that almost every quote comes from actual people like her.
You think she's bad?
Try [this](https://theestablishment.co/yes-trans-women-can-get-period-symptoms-e43a43979e8c) ... Which is pretty par for the course.

> i'll gladly help them if they want to bleed from their genitals once a month

Comment: Umm Maybe consider editing your post to make it a bit clearer what your answer really is. Also that line at the end is that a quote or just a bit of a weird saying?

Comment: Wow. So, this is a good answer, but it's getting some downvotes because it could use some clarification. "Also, Graywytch has been massively toned down. The author rewrote her three times because no one would find her believable." Very interesting! Could you put in the quote from the author where they say this...I'd love to see it?

Comment: Also, it looks like you were going to provide a quote from a real-life person who thinks something similar, but maybe forgot. That would be great for the answer. Also, do these real-life people hate transgender women while being less upset about cisgender men?
 And finally, I don't quite get the last line...?